# What is this Beethoven piece?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, beethoven

I found an mp3 on my PC, marked as Fur Elise by Beethoven. I recognise the piece, but know it's not Fur Elise.

Can anyone tell me what it is? Here is a link to a cut-down version (as I'm sure you'll recognise it within seconds, so I cut it down to save bandwidth)...

https://pixata.co.uk/MyBits/Beethoven.mp3

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the second movement of Mozart's Piano Concerto no.21 in C, K467
[image]

Comment: Ha ha, so it wasn't even Beethoven at all! Thanks very much for sorting it out. Have to go and find the rest of the concerto now, see if it's as nice as that movement